# Backbone.js save always triggers error even on success

Tags: backbone.js

I've read several of the other posts about this problem and none of the solutions seem to be working for me.  I have the following code in my View:

```
  this.model.set({
      username: $('#user-username').val(),
      role: $('#user-role').val(),
      description: $('#user-description').val()
  });

  this.model.save({ user_id: this.model.get('user_id')}, {
    success: function(user, response) {
      console.log('success:', response);
      $('.flash-message').text("Success").show();
    }, 
    error: function(user, response) {
      console.log('error:', response);
      $('.flash-message').text(response.error).show();
    } 
  });
```

and this on my server controller (nodejs running express 3):

```
UserController.prototype.updateAction = function(req, res) {
if (req.route.method != "put") {                              
    res.send({status: "error", error: "update must be put action and must include values"});
    return false;                                             
}
var query = {'user_id': req.params.id};                       
var user = req.body;
var userRepository = this.userRepository                      

// delete _id to avoid errors
delete user._id;

userRepository.update(query, user, {}, function(err, updated) {
    if ((err) || (!updated)) {
        res.send({"status": "error", "error": err});
        return false;
    }
    // send updated user back
    util.log('updated user ' + user.user_id);
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.status(200);
    res.send(JSON.stringify({"status": "success", "updated": updated}));
});
```

}

On save, my model is saved correctly in the server and I have verified the server response with [this](http://json.parser.online.fr/). So, as far as I can tell the server is returning status 200, valid JSON, with a valid JSON response header.  And yet my backbone model.save function always triggers the error callback.  Can anyone please tell me why and how to resolve this?

I am able to get this to work if set the dataType to text like so:

```
this.model.save({ user_id: this.model.get('user_id')}, {
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(user, response) {
      console.log('success:', response);
      $('.flash-message').text("Success").show();
    }, 
    error: function(user, response) {
      console.log('error:', response);
      $('.flash-message').text(response.error).show();
    }
  });
```

but doing so does not allow me to get the response back from the server.  Instead I get this in the response var:

```
success: {
  "_id": "5133b02062e15ed1d2000001",
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Backbone expects to get back the model that it sent in its PUT or POST request body.

Instead of:

```
res.send(JSON.stringify({"status": "success", "updated": updated}));
```

Try this in your server's response:

```
res.json(user);
```

Answer (score 0):

There may be a possibility that your call may have got in state 200 connection established which backbone detects as error, Backbone throws success only when the call is 200OK.

Answer (score 0):

What's your server code? You need to make sure you're sending json back to backbone like so:

```
//In your express POST route
user.save(function(err) {
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
        return res.json(401);
    } else {
        console.log('user: ' +user.username + ' saved');
        return res.json(200);
    }
```

Then in your backbone view you can check for the response and do what you need:

```
//some function in your view
this.model.save(this.formValues, {
            success: function(model, response, options) {
                if (response == 200) { 
                    console.log('success :' + response);
                    //Do stuff
                } else {
                    console.log('error: '+response);
                //etc.
```

Also note that as per the backbone model documentation: 
"save accepts success and error callbacks in the options hash, which will be passed the arguments (model, response, options)"